# How do I set two different Texts for my RecyclerView Row?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view with a row.xml that includes two textviews and some buttons. What I'm trying to accomplish is to let the user choose a date on a calendarView and change that into a String. After it should also show the name of the Item that the user inputed. My problem is that instead of having the Date and the Name of the item in one row. It shows two rows that has the same values in each textViews. So example. Row 1 = textview(Hello), textView(Hello)
Row 2 = TextView(march14), Textview(march 14).

This is my RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> mDataset){
    this.mDataset = mDataset;
}

@Override
public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row_inventory, parent, false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItemName.setText(mDataset.get(position));
    holder.mItemDate.setText(mDataset.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mItemName;
    public TextView mItemDate;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemNameTxtView);
        mItemDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expirationDateTxtView);
    }
}
```

And this is my Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_freezer);

    mDataset = new ArrayList<>();

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.FreezerInventoryRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(mDataset);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    AddFreezerItems = findViewById(R.id.addItemsFreezer);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("itemInfo1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = prefs.getString("FoodName1", null);
        String date = prefs.getString("ExpirationDate1", null);
        mDataset.add(name);
        mDataset.add(date);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("itemName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = preferences.edit();
    editor1.clear();
    editor1.apply();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your datatype - currently an `ArrayList<String>`

Create a POJO to hold your ROW information, one item should contain all data to populate one row.

POJO:

```
public class Event {

        private final String name;
        private final String date;

        public Event(String name, String date) {
            this.name = name;
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
    }
```

To Create an item:

```
mDataset = new ArrayList<Event>(); // change your current instance variable from String to Event type

String name = prefs.getString("FoodName1", null);
String date = prefs.getString("ExpirationDate1", null);

mDataset.add(new Event(name, date));
```

Your dataset, for example would be:

```
public ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Event> mDataset){
    this.mDataset = mDataset;
}
```

When you bind data:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mItemName.setText(mDataset.get(position).getName());
    holder.mItemDate.setText(mDataset.get(position).getDate());
}
```

Comment: I will try later when I get back home Thank you :)

Comment: You have made this so easy for me Thank you!

Comment: Just wondering if you knew why my recycler view shows one empty row like its in the list but when I add items, it just replaces it.